# Sequence convergence test fails

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $$b_1 = 1, b_{n+1} = \frac12\left(b_n+\frac{\beta}{b_n}\right)$$ where $\beta$ is a positive number.

I'm don't know how is possible that given $$f(x) = \frac12\left(x+\frac{\beta}{x}\right)$$ to be incresing for $x>\sqrt{\beta}$ (and I already proved that $b_n\geq\sqrt{\beta}$) and $b_{n+1}\leq b_n$ (because $\frac{b_n^2}{b_n^2+\beta^2}\geq\frac{2a_n^2}{a_n^2+a_n^2}$)

Can someone explain how this is possible?

Thanks for attention

Answer (score 2):

$$b_{n+1}-\sqrt{\beta} =\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b_n-\sqrt{\beta}}{\sqrt{b_n}}\right)^2$$
$$b_{n+1}+\sqrt{\beta} =\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{b_n+\sqrt{\beta}}{\sqrt{b_n}}\right)^2$$
$$\Longrightarrow  \frac{b_{n+1}-\sqrt{\beta}}{b_{n+1}+\sqrt{\beta}} =\left(\frac{b_n-\sqrt{\beta}}{b_n+\sqrt{\beta}}\right)^2=...= \left(\frac{b_1-\sqrt{\beta}}{b_1+\sqrt{\beta}}\right)^{2^{n}}$$
as $|1-\sqrt{\beta}|<|1+\sqrt{\beta}|$, we deduce that
$$\frac{b_{n+1}-\sqrt{\beta}}{b_{n+1}+\sqrt{\beta}}  \to0$$
or $b_n$ converges